# Keep Dynamic Inequality Constraints Feasible in Portfolio Optimization Problem in Python

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, portfolio

To avoid concentration at the top in a portfolio optimization problem, I am using cVaR style inequality constraints. For example, the weights of the 25% of constituents with the smallest weights need to add up to more than 10%.

This constraint is defined in the following way:

```
n_smallest   = int(len(constituents)*0.25)
con1         = {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum(sorted(x)[:n_smallest])-0.1}
```

To keep the constraints feasible I have implemented Non-Linear constraints as well in the following way, setting the "keep_feasible" flag to True:

```
n_smallest = int(number_of_constituents*key)
constraint = NonlinearConstraint(fun=lambda x: sum(sorted(x)[:n_smallest_temp]), lb=min_weight, ub=1, keep_feasible=True)
```

I am using the following optimizer:

```
global_opt   = scipy.optimize.minimize(objective_function=sharpe, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=[con1]}
```

When checking the solution from the optimizer, the inequality constraint is not fulfilled and the weight of the 25% constituents with smallest weights does not always add up to 10%.

When I run below multiple times, I tend to get vastly different results and I believe this is due to the inequality constraints not being evaluated at every optimization step. Did anyone run into a similar problem and has solved it?

**1.Is there a way to make the scipy minimize optimizer check all constraints at every step?**

**2.Is there an alternative method that is able to use conditional inequality constraints?**

I have also tried to use a different optimizer, i.e. the differential evolution optimizer, but this has not helped either. I would really appreciate your help on this.

Please find a minimal reproducible example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import warnings
#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from random import gauss, randint
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint
from scipy.sparse.construct import rand

class PortfolioOptimization(object):
    def __init__(self, number_of_constituents, ineq_constraints):
        self.ineq_constraints   = ineq_constraints
        self.num_const          = number_of_constituents
        self.returns_const      = pd.DataFrame([self.generate_random_returns() for i in range(self.num_const)]).T #20 constituents
        self.returns_objective  = pd.DataFrame(self.generate_random_returns(), columns=["portfolio_to_estimate"])

    def generate_inequality_constraints(self, inequality_constraints, number_of_constituents):
        constraints         = []
        for key in inequality_constraints.keys():
            min_weight      = inequality_constraints[key]
            n_smallest_temp = int(number_of_constituents*key)
            temp_constraint = {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: sum(sorted(x)[:n_smallest_temp])-min_weight}
            constraints.append(temp_constraint)
        return constraints

    def generate_nonlinear_constraints(self, inequality_constraints, number_of_constituents):
        constraints         = []
        for key in inequality_constraints.keys():
            min_weight      = inequality_constraints[key]
            n_smallest_temp = int(number_of_constituents*key)
            temp_constraint = NonlinearConstraint(fun=lambda x: sum(sorted(x)[:n_smallest_temp]), lb=min_weight, ub=1, keep_feasible=True)
            constraints.append(temp_constraint)
        return constraints

    def check_inequality_constraints(self, weights_dict):
        ineq_constraints    = self.ineq_constraints
        weights_dict        = {k: v for k, v in sorted(weights_dict.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1])}
        for key in ineq_constraints.keys():
            min_weight      = ineq_constraints[key]
            n_smallest_temp = int(self.num_const*key)
            weight_n_small  = sum(list(weights_dict.values())[-n_smallest_temp:])
            if weight_n_small<min_weight:
                print(f"Concentration constraint not fulfilled. Smallest {key*100}% have weight of {weight_n_small} (<{min_weight})")
            else:
                print(f"Smallest {key*100}% have weight of {weight_n_small} (>{min_weight})")

    def generate_random_returns(self, mean=0.015, volatility=0.03, datapoints=200):
        #rand_inte       = randint(1,10)/10
        random_numbers  = [gauss(mean, volatility) for i in range(datapoints)]
        return random_numbers

    def correlation_portfolio(self, weights):
        #weights_dict        = {key: value for key, value in zip(range(self.num_const), weights)}
        #self.check_inequality_constraints(weights_dict)
        portfolio_returns   = pd.concat([np.sum(self.returns_const*weights, axis=1), self.returns_objective], axis=1)
        portfolio_returns.rename(columns={0: 'portfolio_returns'}, inplace=True)

        correlations    = portfolio_returns.corr()
        correlation     = correlations["portfolio_returns"].loc["portfolio_to_estimate"]
        #print(correlation)
        return -correlation

    def portfolio_optimization(self, ineq_constraints, non_linear_constraints=False):
        bounds              = self.num_const *[(0,1)] #20 constituents, min weight 0, max weight 1
        x0                  = self.num_const *[1/self.num_const ]

        if non_linear_constraints:
            constraints     = self.generate_nonlinear_constraints(inequality_constraints=ineq_constraints, number_of_constituents=number_of_const)
        else:
            constraints     = self.generate_inequality_constraints(inequality_constraints=ineq_constraints, number_of_constituents=number_of_const)
        constraints         = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum(x)-1}]+constraints #weights add up to 1
        constraints         = constraints+[{"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum([el for el in x if el<0.05])-0.5}] #sum of all weights bigger than 0.05 is smaller than 0.5

        optimum             = minimize(self.correlation_portfolio, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, options={"disp": False}, constraints=constraints).x
        weights_dict        = {key: value for key, value in zip(range(self.num_const), optimum)}
        self.check_inequality_constraints(weights_dict)
        return weights_dict

ineq_constraints= {0.25: 0.1, 0.5: 0.25, 0.75: 0.5, 0.9: 0.3} #smallest 25% need to have at least 10% weight, 50% smallest need to have at least 25% weight and 75% smallest need to have at least 50% weight
number_of_const = 30

pf_optim        = PortfolioOptimization(number_of_constituents=number_of_const, ineq_constraints=ineq_constraints)
weights_dict    = pf_optim.portfolio_optimization(ineq_constraints=ineq_constraints)
weights_dict    = pf_optim.portfolio_optimization(ineq_constraints=ineq_constraints, non_linear_constraints=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when defining constraints by lambda expressions inside a loop. Let's consider the loop inside `generate_inequality_constraints`:

```py
inequality_constraints = {0.25: 0.1, 0.5: 0.25, 0.75: 0.5, 0.9: 0.3}
number_of_constituents = 30
constraints = []
for key in inequality_constraints.keys():
    min_weight      = inequality_constraints[key]
    n_smallest_temp = int(number_of_constituents*key)
    temp_constraint = {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: sum(sorted(x)[:n_smallest_temp])-min_weight}
    constraints.append(temp_constraint)
```

The problem here is that the variables `min_weight` and `n_smallest_temp` are not local to the lambdas. This means that they are defined when the lambdas are called, not when they are defined. Thus, each lambda expression uses the same values for `min_weight` and `n_smallest_temp` at the end of the loop! This can easily be verified by evaluating each of your constraints for the same point `x0`:

```py
In [3]: x0 = np.ones(30)/30
   ...: for con in constraints:
   ...:      print(con['fun'](x0))
   ...:
0.5999999999999999
0.5999999999999999
0.5999999999999999
0.5999999999999999
```

Each constraint returns the same value. Long story short, you need to *capture the values of the variables*:

```py
inequality_constraints = {0.25: 0.1, 0.5: 0.25, 0.75: 0.5, 0.9: 0.3}
number_of_constituents = 30
constraints = []
for key in inequality_constraints.keys():
    m = inequality_constraints[key]
    k = int(number_of_constituents*key)
    temp_constraint = {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x, k=k, m=m: sum(sorted(x)[:k])-m}
    constraints.append(temp_constraint)
```

Now the constraints can be evaluated as expected:

```py
In [5]: for con in constraints:
   ...:      print(con['fun'](x0))
   ...:
0.1333333333333333
0.24999999999999994
0.23333333333333328
0.5999999999999999
```

Proceed similarly for the other constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Joni. Unfortunately the algorithm is still unable to find the optimum when using differential evolution algorithm. It fails with message: "Solution does not satisfy the constraints, MaxCV= ". Do you see any issues with the constraints? Is there a way to find the global optimum consistently or at least find the same optimum every time?